# JAX-RS doesn't set correct http status code

Tags: java, rest

REST service (Implementation - Apache-cxf) api url is

> /customer/{customerId}

```
@GET
@Path("/{customerId}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getCustomer(@PathParam("customerId") Long customerId) throws Exception {

}
```

customerId is of type Long but if i'm passing string, it throws 404 exception whereas i was expecting service to throw 400 exception. Do i have to explicitly set the http status code ? Wouldn't JAX-RS will do this ?

Comment: You have to be more specific about your implementation and the tools you're using, in this way it will be more easy for others to help you.
By the way you have to implement by yourself the code for the errors management.

Comment: I think Apache cxf does correctly because in your case, it must process response as request not found so status 404 is correct.

Comment: @Loc IMO, it should have been Bad Request, because client didn't pass the correct input.

Comment: It is your expectation. It is bad request right. but since customerId is PATH PARAM, NOT request query param. SO 404 is correct.

Comment: @Loc ok, so is there any way to change the status code in this case ? I could've manipulated the status code, if request reaches to implementation.

Comment: Not sure this is what you want: http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest%252Fresponse%253F

Comment: Loc is right, it's 404 because a method with that signature simply doesn't exist. You could define the same method that accepts a string, and in that one put the generation of the error that you want, but it doesn't sound good to me.